# JDBC-LAN-MySQL implementation

Tags: mysql, jdbc, lan

i am creating an application with client-server architecture in java. What i am trying to achieve is a simple client-server architecture connected via LAN with a ethernet switch, the server is having a server module of application running and also having MySQL database, the clients do their processing and submit results on server database, database also used for authentication.
the Server would be the only machine in network that will be connected to WAN through any ISP, the IP address of server machine cannot be *guaranteed* to be static, in this condition *how the clients may connect to the server database*?  As the IP address of server is fluid..

One more doubt is that i've to authenticate the clients also on the basis of there IP addresses (or it may also be physical MAC address, if simple to implement), i've a table in database that the server admin can update and stores the IP addresses of valid clients, now on connecting via LAN what will be the IP addresses allocated to the machines to be stored in database and *will they be static*? i've googled for this but did not found relevant answers...
I hope i am clear with my question .I am sorry if the question is not related to stackoverflow,but it contains programming with database and networking too.


Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it you have a few separate problems:
1. The IP addresses on the client machine are probably NOT static - a very high proportion of users are allocated dynamic addresses by their ISPs
2. There is no way to reliably connect to your Server as it has no static IP address.

The first problem can be solved by using the MAC address as you suggest (although this is easy to spoof if an attacker wants to)  or some locally stored access keys.

The second is much more difficult (and really the reason why we have static IP addresses) - you need to use a VPN or some kind of forwarding service which does have a fixed IP afaik.

Comment: clients are connected to just LAN not internet,so will they do not have static IPs yet?